# Div not being echod in mysql result php

Tags: php, mysql, echo

**So first of let me past my code**

```
<div class="Page_Navigation"><?php 
$sql = "SELECT id, name, banner, description, sponsor, votes, hits FROM websites"; 
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql); //run the query
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); ?>
<div class="Page_Navigation"><?
echo "<a href='index.php?page=1'>".'<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
    echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
echo "<a href='index.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>'."</a> "; // Goto last page
?></div>
```

**And here is an image of what it looks like:**
[image]

**And this is what it is supposed to be:**
[image]

**Not only that, but the links are dead:**

> page=

Comment: your div is inside of your for loop move it above it

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used.

Comment: Welcome to The Stack Ibrahim

Comment: You're generating `<div><a></a><div><a></a>.....</div>`. you have a zillion div OPENS, and only one div CLOSE.

Comment: Tried that, but still not displaying the fancy div: http://prntscr.com/7spoy5

Comment: Why don't you also view source take a look at the actual HTML to see what you're missing?

Comment: @Zsw http://prntscr.com/7sprib

Comment: @DipenShah Here's a [useful link for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Thank you @Machavity I'll make sure I include that link in future `mysql_*` comments.

Comment: I edited for loop syntax just check that and see its working or not.

Comment: I wish to say thanks for all those who helped me on this. I am now in a pickle with choosing the best answer to mark :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. See the code:-

Try to move your `div code` before `for loop`:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // check all type of error
ini_set('display_errors',1); // display errors if any
$conn = mysqli_connect('server name','user name','password','database name') or die(mysqli_connect_error); // connect to database

$sql = "SELECT id, name, banner, description, sponsor, votes, hits FROM websites"; 
$rs_result = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); //run the query
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

echo "<a href='index.php?page=1'>".''."</a>"; // Go to 1st page 
echo '<div class="Page_Navigation">'; 
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 

    echo "<a href=index.php?page=$i>$i</a>";
 }

  echo "<a href=index.php?page=$total_pages></a></div>"; // Go to last page
 ?>
```

Comment: I wish to say thanks for all those who helped me on this. I am now in a pickle with choosing the best answer to mark :(

Comment: you need to chose that one which is using current syntaxes, and also gives you proper information.

Comment: Giving it to you, not only helping but for giving the extra information for  Mysqli and PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move div befor `for` loop

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT id, name, banner, description, sponsor, votes, hits FROM websites"; 
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql); //run the query
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

echo "<a href='index.php?page=1'>".''."</a>"; // Goto 1st page 
echo '<div class="Page_Navigation">'; 
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
    echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
}

echo "<a href='index.php?page=$total_pages'>".''."</a></div> "; // Goto last page
?>
```

Add to `.css` file the class:

```
.Page_Navigation {
   padding: 5px;
   background: #dedede;
   margin: 5px;
}
```

Or somewhere in the file:

```
<style>
.Page_Navigation {
   padding: 5px;
   background: #dedede;
   margin: 5px;
}
</style>
```

I haven't checked if the colors match or the distance, so you need to change that :)

Comment: No need for `;` after `}`

Comment: That works, although the boxes are not showing? ( div )

Comment: @Ibrahim What creates the boxes?

Comment: This has worked, although there is 1 problem now. The page?= does not give you a link see photo:http://prntscr.com/7spsve

Comment: My css creates the boxes

Comment: I wish to say thanks for all those who helped me on this. I am now in a pickle with choosing the best answer to mark :(